# Mac Pro 5.1 Windows 10 boot problems

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, filesystem

I'm trying to run Win 10 on a separated drive attached to sata optical drive bay. I ran into some issues about GPT partition over instalation processes which I could solve it by terminal commands. It was installed, booted up but after restarting it doesn’t boot anymore, it restarts on every attempt.
I’m running a Mac Pro 2010, Sierra OSX.
Please, would someone help me with that?

Comment: Why did you choose the optical drive bay? Does not a 2010 Mac Pro have extra HDD/SDD drive bays?

Comment: Yes it has, but the answer is quite simple, it had already been occupied. I don't have an extra adapter for that SSD (dindn't mention that, sorrry).

Comment: If the replacement drive is a SSD, does this drive operate with Negotiated Link Speed of 6 Gigabit? You can determine this by using the System Information application. Look for SATA/SATA Express under Hardware.

Comment: I've already got an 1TB SSD in the main bay for Mac OS, just adding a second one (128GB) for Windows. You can't get that speed from SATA2 unfortunately, but you won't see any difference at least you are managing huge files.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on your comment which is repeated below.

> It was running smoothly on UEFI boot, but after a graphic card driver update it doesn't boot anymore.

Another possible solution would be to disable Windows Update from downloading and installing driver updates. This can be done using the Local Group Policy Editor (This requires Widows 10 Pro are better.) or [from the control panel](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-automatic-driver-downloads-on-windows-10).

The Control Panel steps for Windows 10 (version 1803) are given below.

1. From the Start menu select `Window System`, then select `Control Panel`.
2. Select View by: `Small icons`.
3. Select `System`.
4. Select `Advanced system settings`.
5. Select `Hardware` tab.
6. Select `Device Installation Settings`
7. Select `No`
8. Select `Save Changes`.

This will require you to reinstall Windows. I suggest not connecting to the internet until you have disabled driver updates and installed the Window Support Software from Apple.

You may also want to try to see if you can get Windows 10 to [Safe Boot](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10). Boot from the Windows 10 installation media (DVD or USB flash drive) and at the first menu enter the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> key combination. Enter the following command in the window.

```
bcdedit  /set  {default}  safeboot  minimal
```

Close all windows to restart the Mac. If you can get Windows to boot, then maybe you could rollback the graphic device driver.

Comment: Everything went ok, thank you so much. Windows couldn't find the GeForce GT 120 driver but I found it manualy. The only remain issue is about my GTX 980ti which Windows found the driver automaticaly but it is behavoring weird like not allowing to open windows explorer, missing some items in the bottom bar and other things. I'll try to install it by myself later, didn't have time yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some realities regarding what you are attempting.

- Windows should be installed using the BIOS boot method on all 2010 Mac models. The primary reason for this is the Windows Support Software from Apple assumes a BIOS booting install of Windows.
- The drive(s) used to install Windows need to be hybrid partitioned. This means the GUID Partition Table (GPT) is used for macOS and the MBR partition table is used for Windows.
- Usually, installing 64 bit Windows 10 on a 2010 Mac should work, even though Apple does not officially support this configuration.
- You should use the Window Support Software downloaded using the Boot Camp Assistant on your 2010 Mac or by directly downloading from [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5621](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US). Basically, you are using Windows 7 drivers for a Windows 10 install. Windows is designed to accept older drivers when new ones are unavailable.
- I believe you are suppose to temporarily remove the primary drive when installing Windows on a secondary drive with the 2010 Mac Pro. Although, this could be overcome by installing a small Windows boot partition on the primary drive. Most of Windows 10 would then reside on the drive in the optical drive bay. Basically, you boot Windows from the primary drive and Windows then transfers control to the secondary drive.

Comment: Thx David, I knew it was possible if a bit fiddly.

Comment: Thanks David, let me just ask you some questions to clarify some

Comment: Sorry, I hit return
Thanks David, let me just ask you some questions to clarify some
I'll start every thing again, using the BIOS boot method, you mean by the DVD way?
It was running smoothly on UEFI boot, but after a graphic card driver update it doesn't boot anymore.

Comment: 2010 Macs do not have a UEFI. There is a EFI based on the Intel standard. The UEFI standard was developed from the EFI Intel standard. Windows may have downloaded a driver update which requires a UEFI interface that does not exist in the 2010 Mac firmware. This is why you should install Windows to BIOS  boot.

Comment: By BIOS, I mean when booting the BIOS firmware reads the first 512 bytes stored in the drive and executes the software residing in these bytes. Included in these bytes is the MBR table. The software reads the table and determines which partition to boot from. When a partition boots, the boot software then makes calls the the BIOS to perform startup tasks. Eventually, the drivers take over which may interface directly with hardware and/or make calls to the BIOS functions.

Answer (score -1):

It is important to realize that Apple does not support all versions of Windows on all Macs. It is not that they are not capable, it is just that Apple didn't write drivers for older Macs.

That said if you go [here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990#models](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990#models) you will find that the earliest Mac Pro that supports Windows 10 is the Late 2013 model (sometimes referred to as the trash can or cylinder model).

Tho some people have had success downloading drivers for similar hardware from a manufacturers website that is a bit of a crap shoot and, I believe, off-topic for AskDifferent.

So it is likely that it doesn't work because it is not specifically supported.

Comment: Thanks Steve, that's not the rule of thumb, Apple just not want to be bothered with old models. The grinder model is a 10 years old computer which is faster than most of newer ones. I bet those models will last a couple of years yet.

Comment: For the record, I installed Windows 10 on a 2009 Mac Pro, flashed to think it's a 2010 Mac Pro for purposes of upgrading the CPU, this past weekend and it worked fine, no third-party drivers required (except GPU, which everybody installing Windows on Mac should get the actual drivers for their actual video card from said video card's manufacturer anyway).

Comment: Actually the :"rule of thumb" is to not assume why Apple does anything. And Apple will do anything that will benefit it. Obviously older models are not a priority as they are not making them money any more. I stand by my first paragraph, Apple does not support all versions of Windows on all Macs. Fortunately it is possible to hack some "unsupported" Macs with "unsupported" versions of Windows.